# When I use list.filled() and initialize the value, why do I still prompt for syntax errors?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I use list.filled() and initialize the value, why do I still prompt for syntax errors?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgTKX.png)

Comment: Read that error message again, that message is clear. Check your List type and check the value you are passing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not fill list of widget with number

```dart
List<Widget> list= List.filled(10,SizedBox.shrink());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want List of `int`, define List as `int`.
You defined a List of `Widget` but filled by `int`. See this [enter link description here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-core/List/List.filled.html)

```
List<int> list= List.filled(0,10);
// or
List<Widget> list= List.filled(0,Container());
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you declared your type of your `List` as `Widget`.

```
List<Widget> list = List.filled(0, Container());
```

If you want it as type int then declare it as the following.

```
List<int> list = List.filled(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

as you have declared list with data type widget it can only store widgets like

```
List<Widgets> widgets=[Container(),Container(),Container()];
```

and if you need to store int as data type use this code

```
List<int> intList=[1,2,3,4,5];
```

by the way dart is smart you do not need to specify data type you can use it just like

```
List data =[];  //store anything here
```